# IE on click of a link opens pop up again and again instead of showing in the same screen

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window.open

When i click on a link in my application header it should open a pop up screen, but when i click on the same link from someother page it is opening in another pop up even though i had not closed the earlier one. This issue is prevailing only in IE and not in other browsers.

```
function popUpForInvoice(url) 
{
   var csrfName = document.getElementById("csrf").getAttribute("name");
   var csrfToken = document.getElementById("csrf").value;
   var newUrl = "/ecommerce/mitac/" + url + "&"+ csrfName + "=" + csrfToken;
   var left = (screen.width/2)-(550/2);
   var top = (screen.height/2)-(550/2);
   var  ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
   var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE");
   if (msie > 0)      
       window.open(newUrl,'_blank','toolbar=0,scrollbars=yes,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=no,width=540,height=600,left ='+left+',top ='+top+'');
else                 
       window.open(newUrl,'about:blank','toolbar=0,scrollbars=yes,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=no,width=540,height=600,left ='+left+',top ='+top+'');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `_blank` as target is DESIGNED to open a new window each time
2. `about:blank`  is not a valid target - use something like `mywindow` to reuse
3. No need for the agent test which by the way will fail in IE11 anyway.
4. some of your parameters are not necessary and spaces are not allowed in the parameters

This should work

Remove

```
var  ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
 var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE");
 if (msie > 0)      
       window.open(newUrl,'_blank','toolbar=0,scrollbars=yes,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=no,width=540,height=600,left ='+left+',top ='+top+'');
else
```

And just have

```
window.open(newUrl,'mywindow',
 'scrollbars,resizable=no,width=540,height=600,left='+left+',top='+top);
```

Do note that you will likely need to focus the window or it will stay under when opened the second and subsequent times